# wpf custom control: draggable/resizable rectangle within another rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking into a control with two rectangles: one inside the other. I want the user to be able to drag the inner rectangle, resize it and if possible rotate it as well within the bounds of the outer rectangle. The values should be bindable so I can store the values in my datasource when updated.

Are there already controls like this or does anyone have any suggestions?

I saw a codeproject article on dragging elements in a canvas but those properties aren't bindable..

Comment: What have you tried? How about xaml of what is needed. I get that this issue is old; so is it still an issue?

Answer (score 21):

[This guy on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=65924) has a series of articles that do exactly what I think you're looking for. I expect the first article will be of most help to you, but the entire series is good.

[1. Drag, resize, and rotate elements on a canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part1.aspx)

[2. Designer Canvas with Zoombox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx)

[3. Connecting Items](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part3.aspx)

[4. A frankenbuild](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This : [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/zoomandpancontrol.aspx) is something quite similar. If you can't find anything that suits you more then it is in my opinion a good base to start.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that is really a solution to what I'm looking for.