# Resizable and movable usercontrols within a tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a tabcontrol that is dynamically populated by various usercontrols of various sizes.  I'd like to let the user resize and move those usercontrols like normal windows within each tabitem.  Is this possible?  How is it done?

Comment: Can you share more information on how yor tabcontrol is populated?

Comment: That's quite a [poor quality question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too. Please read the linked page to see how you can improve it... help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can put a `Canvas` control in your `TabItem` and add your `UserControl`s to the `Canvas.Children` collection. You can set their initial positions using the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties and move them using a `TranslateTransform`:

```
<TabItem>
    <Canvas Name="YourCanvas" />
</TabItem>

...

SomeControl someControl = new SomeControl();
someControl.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
Canvas.SetLeft(someControl, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(someControl, 100);
YourCanvas.Children.Add(someControl);
```

I won't explain the *whole* thing to you here, as it's already been written. I'd rather direct you to read through the [How to move WPF controls with mouse at runtime](http://denismorozov.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/drag-controls-in-wpf-using.html) page from denis morozov's blog.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the "Canvas". The canvas allows you to have kind of floating controls within another control.  In this instance you'd put a canvas inside your tab item, and then populate the canvas with your dynamic usercontrols. More information can be found at [this stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019367/wpf-custom-control-draggable-resizable-rectangle-within-another-rectangle)

It's possible that you might want to use [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx) instead, but based on your description they're not exactly what you are looking for (mostly because it's much more complicated).